# How can I scrape LinkedIn company pages with cURL and PHP? No CSRF token found in headers error

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, web-crawler, linkedin-api

I want to scrape some LinkedIn company pages with cURL and PHP. The API of LinkedIn is not build for that, so I have to do this with PHP. If there are any other options, please let me know...

Before scraping the company page I have to sign in at LinkedIn with a personal account via cURL, but it doesn't seems to work.

I've got a 'No CSRF token found in headers' error.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks!

```
<?php

require_once 'dom/simple_html_dom.php';

$linkedin_login_page = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login";

$username = 'linkedin_username';
$password = 'linkedin_password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linkedin_login_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$login_content = str_get_html(curl_exec($ch));

if(curl_error($ch)) {
  echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

if ($login_content) {

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=isJsEnabled]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=isJsEnabled]') as $element) {

      $isJsEnabled = trim($element->value);

      if ($isJsEnabled === "false") {
        $isJsEnabled = "true";
      }

    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=source_app]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=source_app]') as $element) {
      $source_app = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=tryCount]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=tryCount]') as $element) {
      $tryCount = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=clickedSuggestion]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=clickedSuggestion]') as $element) {
      $clickedSuggestion = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=session_redirect]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=session_redirect]') as $element) {
      $session_redirect = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=trk]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=trk]') as $element) {
      $trk = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=loginCsrfParam]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=loginCsrfParam]') as $element) {
      $loginCsrfParam = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=fromEmail]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=fromEmail]') as $element) {
      $fromEmail = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=csrfToken]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=csrfToken]') as $element) {
      $csrfToken = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

  if (($login_content->find('input[name=sourceAlias]', 0))) {
    foreach($login_content->find('input[name=sourceAlias]') as $element) {
      $sourceAlias = trim($element->value);
    }
  }

}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'isJsEnabled='.$isJsEnabled.'&source_app='.$source_app.'&tryCount='.$tryCount.'&clickedSuggestion='.$clickedSuggestion.'&session_key='.$username.'&session_password='.$password.'&session_redirect='.$session_redirect.'&trk='.$trk.'&loginCsrfParam='.$loginCsrfParam.'&fromEmail='.$fromEmail.'&csrfToken='.$csrfToken.'&sourceAlias='.$sourceAlias);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$store = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/facebook');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $content;

?>
```

Comment: Your question will probably be closed because it is not super clear what you are asking for and the code you provided isn't really referenced in your question nor are specific questions asked about it. BUT you should take a look at this Python website scraping framework called [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/), it makes extracting content from websites pretty easy and even allows you to have your scrapers log in to LinkedIn so you can view content. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Noah, Thanks for mentioning Scrapy. I think my question is pretty clear; How can I scrape the LinkedIn company pages with cURL and PHP?

Comment: Try to ask more specific questions, cURL and PHP are 2 huge tools/technologies. Try to clarify what you have done and what exactly isn't working.

Comment: The authentication is not working. I've got a 'No CSRF token found in headers' error

Comment: There we go! I saw that you also edited your question with this info, good job. As you will soon figure out whether or not your question gets answered on this site has almost 100% to do with how you ask it. Checkout [this guide about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for the login , if you want to make sure that is working just save the content in a file and you will see that the login was successful

instead of using simple_html_dom we used above fetch_value, you still can use
simple_html_dom

```
<?php
function fetch_value($str, $find_start = '', $find_end = '')
{
    if ($find_start == '')
    {
        return '';
    }
    $start = strpos($str, $find_start);
    if ($start === false)
    {
        return '';
    }
    $length = strlen($find_start);
    $substr = substr($str, $start + $length);
    if ($find_end == '')
    {
        return $substr;
    }
    $end = strpos($substr, $find_end);
    if ($end === false)
    {
        return $substr;
    }
    return substr($substr, 0, $end);
}

$linkedin_login_page = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login";
$linkedin_ref = "https://www.linkedin.com";

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linkedin_login_page);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $linkedin_ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');


$login_content = curl_exec($ch);


if(curl_error($ch)) {
  echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

$var = array(
            'isJsEnabled' => 'false',
            'source_app' => '',
            'clickedSuggestion' => 'false',
            'session_key' => trim($username),
            'session_password' => trim($password),
            'signin' => 'Sign In',
            'session_redirect' => '',
            'trk' => '',
            'fromEmail' => '');
        $var['loginCsrfParam'] = fetch_value($login_content, 'type="hidden" name="loginCsrfParam" value="', '"');
        $var['csrfToken'] = fetch_value($login_content, 'type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="', '"');
        $var['sourceAlias'] = fetch_value($login_content, 'input type="hidden" name="sourceAlias" value="', '"');

        $post_array = array();
            foreach ($var as $key => $value)
            {
                $post_array[] = urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
            }
        $post_string = implode('&', $post_array);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

$store = curl_exec($ch);


if (stripos($store, "session_password-login-error") !== false){
    $err = trim(strip_tags(fetch_value($store, '<span class="error" id="session_password-login-error">', '</span>')));
    echo "Login error : ".$err;
}elseif (stripos($store, 'profile-nav-item') !== false) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/10667/?pathWildcard=10667');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "");
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo $content;
}else{
    echo "unknown error";
}


?>
```

You will notice that the company page doesn't load , as linkedin has just changed their design and their company links to keep tracking opened companies pages.

Comment: Thankssss, it works! The data of the company pages is in the source, so you can scrape that... Is a proxy and a fake account recommend?

Comment: Yes I recommend to use only a fake account as it may be closed

Comment: Hi, I have tried to implement your code, but it's returning an error
saying
"You must be authenticated to access this page." after entering the block start from line no 84 of your code

Comment: @faxsy Hi, i'm getting a "You must be authenticated to access this page" response just like tonmoy

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to scrape the login, just login with your browser and copy the session cookie to your curl script.  This will trick linked in to thinking it is just you on your web browser.  Sometimes web servers are smart enough to look at the other headers passed like browser type and invalidate the request if that is the case, just make sure that you set the same headers in your curl script as the browser you use to login with.  Let me know if you need me to explain how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Mike for helping me out... I don't know exactly what you mean. You mean I can store the cookie 'JSESSIONID' of LinkedIn in my local browser to my curl script? Could you explain me how to do that? Does that also work on a different server instead of local?

Comment: Since the OP is already getting a  'No CSRF token found in headers' error then I very much doubt this will work.  This technique is, to all practical purposes, a CSRF attack!  So if they have CSRF protection, it should stop this approach.

Comment: @Adam you should check my answer above, the CSRF was bypassed and the login process went good.

Comment: @Adam, lol, no that's not what a CSRF is.  It is, however a session hijack.

Comment: @MilanPasschier I would just go with the solution Faxsy gave if it works.  Let me know if it doesn't though.

Comment: @MikeSchem the solution of Faxsy works, thanks for your help!

Comment: @MikeSchem: yes, it's not technically a CSRF.  But is is close enough that any site with CSRF protection is likely to also prevent a simple session hijack by just copying the session cookie.  Not all session hijacks are CSRF, no, but CSRF is effectively a subset of session hijacking and the protection should cover both

Comment: @Adam if the session cookie and all the headers are copied from the browser that initiates the session on the same computer, there is no possible way for the server to know if the session is hijacked.  Call it what you want.

Comment: @MikeSchem: If you also copy all the post data yes.  As long as the token doesn't change when you move forward.